# Dirichlet distribution with RcppGSL

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, gsl

I have a Gibbs sampler currently written in R, and I'm trying to make it faster using the package `Rcpp` and `RcppGSL`. What is causing me problems right now is that I can't seem to be able to use the random variate generator for the dirichlet distribution. Here's a short script that doesn't work on my computer:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>

#include <RcppGSL.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppGSL)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]

NumericVector rdirichlet_cpp(NumericVector alpha) {
  int n = alpha.size();
  NumericVector results(n);

  // Allocate random number generator
  gsl_rng *r = gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_mt19937);

  gsl_ran_dirichlet(r, n, alpha, results);

  // Release random number generator
  gsl_rng_free(r);

  return(results);
}
```

When I try to source this using `sourceCpp()`, I get an error message, saying that there is `no matching function for call to 'gsl_ran_dirichlet'`. I have close to no experience with C/C++, so I may be making a stupid mistake (I'm still not quite sure how `Rcpp` manages memory). But perhaps the issue is actually with the `RcppGSL` package, that somehow it is linked to an older version of GSL which does not contain the Dirichlet random variate generator...

For what it's worth, I also recently implemented that same Gibbs sampler in Python, using the GSL RNG (on the same computer), and everything seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You report a different error from the one I see:

```
gsldiri.cpp: In function ‘Rcpp::NumericVector rdirichlet_cpp(Rcpp::NumericVector)’:
gsldiri.cpp:20:41: error: cannot convert ‘Rcpp::NumericVector {aka Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>}’ to ‘const double*’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘void gsl_ran_dirichlet(const gsl_rng*, size_t, const double*, double*)’
   gsl_ran_dirichlet(r, n, alpha, results);
                                         ^
make: *** [gsldiri.o] Error 1
```

and this one makes perfect sense:  You somewhat randomly inserted the `Rcpp::NumericVector()` as a third argument to a GSL function which knows nothing about Rcpp.  That cannot work.

Re-read the RcppGSL documentation and examples more carefully.  This is fixable, but it needs a different approach.

*Edit:* Even by GSL standards that interface is somewhat odd. But you do get a somewhat clean solution by replacing your error-causing line with

```
gsl_ran_dirichlet(r, n, alpha.begin(), results.begin());
```

after which it builds and runs---you still need to work on seeding the RNG engine though.  But that is covered in the GSL Reference manual...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I understand better what's going on with Rcpp, but I still need to learn a lot more.

Comment: Please do, and I suggest you hold off making speculative (and wrong) comments about memory performance til you have something that actually compiles :-P

Comment: My comment about memory was merely an example of my lack of knowledge, nothing else. I still don't understand much about how Rcpp sometimes manages memory, but sometimes doesn't. And this is why I need to read more!